# How the update of learning rate is performed in Tensorflow tutorials?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am looking into several tutorials of how to implement learning rate decay while training models using Tensorflow. I noticed in a few examples that it is implemented as follows. For example, in this tutorial on [how to model language using recurrent neural networks](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent):

```
self._lr = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self._lr)
# Some other code...

self._new_lr = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32, shape=[], name="new_learning_rate")
self._lr_update = tf.assign(self._lr, self._new_lr)
```

The learning rate is updated by invoking the following method:

```
def assign_lr(self, session, lr_value):
    session.run(self._lr_update, feed_dict={self._new_lr: lr_value})
```

Then, during training:

```
for i in range(config.max_max_epoch):
    lr_decay = config.lr_decay ** max(i + 1 - config.max_epoch, 0.0)
    m.assign_lr(session, config.learning_rate * lr_decay)
```

Why it is implemented this way? At the first glance it seems to be a bit too complicated. Why something like this wouldn't work?

```
self._lr = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32, shape=[], name="new_learning_rate")
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self._lr)
# Some other code...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self._lr)` will basically create a new optimizer with the modified learning rate every time it is called. But understand that learning rate is not the only parameter in an optimizer and there will be other parameters like **momentum** etc., which will be **reinitialized** on doing so.

Hence correct scheduling would be to keep those other parameters unchanged and just modify the learning rate which is what is done in the tutorial by storing the learning rate as a `tf.Variable` and is updated by calling the function `assign_lr()`.

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the clarification. That is what I needed